# Android - show fragment with custom text in view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I need to show several fragments on the screen. All fragments are instances of one fragment class, but I need to be able to set my values to view attrbutes on these fragments (text in TextView for example). I tried many solutions from here, but didn't find one.
What I'm doing now:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
List<Comment> comments = place.getComments();
int i = 0;
for (Comment comment : comments) { //some cycle...

     ReviewFragment reviewFragment = new ReviewFragment();
     transaction.add(scrollView.getId(), reviewFragment, "review" + i);
     ((TextView) reviewFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.author)).setText(comment.getAuthor());
     i++;

}
transaction.commit();
```

But I get NullPointerException: `reviewFragment.getView()` is null. I tried to commit the transaction and begin new after each fragment, but it didn't helped. How can I set custom values in fragment views?

P.S. I didn't do something special in overriden methods in my ReviewFragment. Should I?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the fragment's method [setArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) when you construct your fragment and pass the text you would like to display. Then inside the ReviewFragment class you can call [getArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()) to retrieve the text and display it.

in the part that you are creating your fragment:

```
ReviewFragment reviewFragment = new ReviewFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("text", "The text to display here");
reviewFragment.setArguments(args);
transaction.add(scrollView.getId(), reviewFragment, "review" + i);
```

and in the onCreateView() of your ReviewFragment

```
// after inflating the view and before returning it
String textToDisplay = getArguments().getString("text");
myTextView.setText(textToDisplay);
```

Comment: What should be argument names? Assume I need to set the text to TextView with id="author", what argument name should I use in this case?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you telling me to display it in ReviewFragment. How can I do it inside of it?